# Any way to prevent losing focus when clicking an input text out of tinymce container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, tinymce

I've made this tinymce [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sBeaab/2) to show what I say.

Highlight text in the editor, then click on the input text, highlight in tinyMCE is lost (obviously).

Now, I know it's not easy since both, the inline editor and the input text are in the same document, thus, the focus is only one. But is there any tinymce way to get like an "unfocused" highlight (gray color) whenever I click in an input text?

I'm saying this because I have a customized color picker, this color picker has an input where you can type in the HEX value, when clicking OK it would execCommand a color change on the selected text, but it looks ugly because the highlight is lost.

I don't want to use an iframe, I know that by using the non-inline editor (iframe) is one of the solutions, but for a few reasons, i can't use an iframe text editor.

Any suggestion here? Thanks.

P.S: Out of topic, does any of you guys know why I can't access to tinymce object in the tinyMCE Fiddle ? looks like the tinyMCE global var was overwritten by the tinymce select dom element of the page itself. I can't execute a tinyMCE command lol.

Comment: complicated, but consider capturing the selection, then re-selecting it before you execute the command.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sBeaab/5

> P.S: Out of topic, does any of you guys know why I can't access to
>   tinymce object in the tinyMCE Fiddle ? looks like the tinyMCE global
>   var was overwritten by the tinymce select dom element of the page
>   itself. I can't execute a tinyMCE command lol.

Well, you can access the tinyMCE variable and even execute commands.

Comment: that's a really good solution that uses `tinyMCE.get('textContainer')` instead of `tinyMCE.activeEditor` to use tiny's remembered selection instead of the fragile dom selection.

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong

> var colorHex = document.getElementById("colorHex")

`colorHex` contains input element, not value.

> var colorHex = document.getElementById("colorHex").value

now it works ( `neolist` couldn't load, so I removed it )

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/DBeaab/1

Comment: thanks for that, but still, the main problem is the focus :( i think it's impossible... unless i use an iframe on the input or the text editor... im screwed.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the focus? - i think there is a solution for almost every tinymce problem

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently.

First off, you can't really have two different elements "selected" simultaneously.  So in order to accomplish this you're going to need to mimic the browser's built-in 'selected text highlight'.  To do this, you're going to have to insert spans into the text to simulate highlighting, and then capture the mousedown and mouseup events.

Here's a fiddle from StackOverflow user "[fullpipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984904/fullpipe)" which illustrates the technique I used.

http://jsfiddle.net/fullpipe/DpP7w/light/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var keylist = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";

        function randWord(length) {

            var temp = '';

            for (var i=0; i < length; i++)

            temp += keylist.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*keylist.length));

        return temp;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        var len = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 3);
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="'+ i +'">' + randWord(len) + '</span> ';
    }

    var start = null;
    var end = null;

    $('body').on('mousedown', function(event) {
        start = null;
        end = null;
        $('span.s').removeClass('s');
        start = $(event.target);
        start.addClass('s');
    });

    $('body').on('mouseup', function(event) {
        end = $(event.target);
        end.addClass('s');
        if(start && end) {
            var between = getAllBetween(start,end);

            for(var i=0, len=between.length; i<len;i++)
                between[i].addClass('s');

            alert('You select ' + (len) + ' words');
        }
    });


});

function getAllBetween(firstEl,lastEl) {

    var firstIdx = $('span').index($(firstEl));
    var lastIdx = $('span').index($(lastEl));

    if(lastIdx == firstIdx)
        return [$(firstEl)];

    if(lastIdx > firstIdx) {
        var firstElement = $(firstEl);
        var lastElement = $(lastEl);
    } else {
        var lastElement = $(firstEl);
        var firstElement = $(lastEl);
    }

    var collection = new Array();
    collection.push(firstElement);
    firstElement.nextAll().each(function(){
        var siblingID  = $(this).attr("id");
        if (siblingID != $(lastElement).attr("id")) {
            collection.push($(this));
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    });

    collection.push(lastElement);
    return collection;
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the gibberish text in the right pane stays highlighted regardless of focus elsewhere on the page.

At that point, you're going to have to apply your color changes to all matching spans.

Comment: looks like a good but i need to work with tinyMCE here, i first thought i could do something like that but adding a fake highlight to the text that i selected might not be the best :( i will try it out tho.